# Azure Active Directory Implementation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am developing an application in which i have to implement sso for azure active directory. I cannot find sufficient information anywhere.

I was following this site [omniauth-azure](https://github.com/AzureAD/omniauth-azure-activedirectory) but i am stuck in one issue

> Returned nonce did not match

Can someone please help me.I am using rails 5 with ruby 2.4.2

Comment: I have searched for ready solution and it doesn't exist. You have to write it by your own

Comment: Do i have to write everything or just the solution for this issue?

Comment: I am not sure about SSO but Oauth has definitely changed for last year. This gem last update was 4 years ago so I guess you have to write your own solution

Comment: There's a similar thread here that might help give some ideas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080115/rails-azure-active-directory-sso-with-web-ios-app-authentication

Comment: Have you seen this issue: https://github.com/AzureAD/omniauth-azure-activedirectory/issues/22?

Comment: I suggest you to try devise saml authenticatable. It's very straight forward and easy to implement.